# Calling Native Code Android Studio: Executable in Assets Dir or Static Library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, native-code

What is the better way to run native executable in Android studio NDK app (assuming you have the source). Assume the following are the two options (please do not suggest to rewrite code in Java):

A. Compile main() into a static library and call it in java. Add outputs to main to get info you want passed to Java app. Dup stdout/stderr to a file in getFilesDir() if you need to capture them for debugging.

B. Put compiled executable in assets folder, copy to getFilesDir() with executable permissions, and run it as an input stream. Parse stdout with redirectErrorStream to get info you want.

My current opinion is A is more efficient and seamless, but I could be wrong. B would save you making an argv and argc to pass to main (maybe makes Java easier to understand by looking like a terminal).